# Encrypt Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, ruby, amazon-web-services

I want to create a RDS with MySQL on it, and I want it to be encrypted.

I am using the Ruby API, and I've looked into the RDS client API, and I saw that there are params that can be given:

```
tde_credential_arn
tde_credential_password
```

but both are related to oracle DB ([Encrypting Amazon RDS Resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html)).
I've also tried to use key storage_encryped and give it a true value, but the key wasn't a valid one (also I've seen it here: [CreateDBInstance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDBInstance.html)).

So, how can i do it with MySQL RDS ?

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html

You basically do this via KMS.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/services-rds.html

and yes, tde is only for oracle/ms